# Would useEffect/lint warnings cause web page to not come up

Tags: warnings, use-effect, lint

After npm start, I see errors, and web page is blank when it comes up:

```
[frontend]   Line 21:6:   React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'register'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
[frontend]
[frontend] ./src/components/user/findProperty/FindProperty.js
[frontend]   Line 47:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'register'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
[frontend]
[frontend] ./src/components/user/dashboard/PastPayments.js
[frontend]   Line 4:8:  'ChevronIcon' is defined but never used   no-unused-vars
[frontend]   Line 5:8:  'DownloadIcon' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
[frontend]
[frontend] ./src/components/common/alerts/Alerts.js
[frontend]   Line 54:6:  React Hook useEffect has an unnecessary dependency: 'fetchAlertData'. Either exclude it or remove the dependency array. Outer scope values like 'fetchAlertData' aren't valid dependencies because mutating them doesn't re-render the component  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
[frontend]
[frontend] ./src/components/user/pastBills/PastBills.js
[frontend]   Line 66:6:   React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'history', 'params', 'serviceAccounts', and 'showFileInUrl'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
[frontend]   Line 93:11:  <iframe> elements must have a unique title property                                                                                                             jsx-a11y/iframe-has-title
[frontend]
[frontend] ./src/components/user/dashboard/CustomerSvcTable.js
[frontend]   Line 7:22:  'formatCurrencyNum' is defined but never used                                                                   no-unused-vars
[frontend]   Line 34:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'getSvcOrder'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
[frontend]
[frontend] ./src/components/user/layout/Layout.js
[frontend]   Line 80:6:   React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'fetchInitialData'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
[frontend]   Line 86:20:  'Tawk_API' was used before it was defined                                                                            no-use-before-define
[frontend]   Line 91:9:   'Tawk_LoadStart' is assigned a value but never used                                                                  no-unused-vars
[frontend]
[frontend] ./src/components/common/navbar/Navbar.js
[frontend]   Line 91:15:  No duplicate props allowed  react/jsx-no-duplicate-props
[frontend]
[frontend] ./src/components/common/card/Card.js
[frontend]   Line 94:21:  Using target="_blank" without rel="noopener noreferrer" is a security risk: see https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener  react/jsx-no-target-blank
[frontend]
[frontend] Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
[frontend] To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.
```

My question is, do I need to add the missing dependencies to the package.json for the frontend? I'm sure they will go away if I do npm install , but I'm unclear on the permanent fix. Do the dependency list items have an order?  The browser popped up with a blank screen but the browser debugging tool doesn't show an error that I can see.  Can I keep ignoring the lint errors and not add them to useEffect like they discuss [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-to-fix-missing-dependency-warning-when-using-useeffect-react-hook)? I'm having trouble finding what/where to add it in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the link was coming up in IE.  When I moved it to Edge, the web page wasn't blank and I didn't see the link warnings.